# T-SQL query to get a date +30 days from today exactly

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

Data is in date/time format and I'm trying to get list of rows where the date is exatly in 30 days from today. This is based on SQL Server 2005.

So on 1st of July, I would get a list of rows where the date is 1st of August.

Example entry would be:

> Sunday, July 04, 1993 12:00 AM

However my query doesn't seem to return any rows at all for some reason.

```
AND DATEPART("month", a.PersonBirthdate) = DATEPART("month", GetDate())
AND DATEPART("day", a.PersonBirthdate) = DATEPART("day", GetDate()+30)
```

For an example, the below query part works fine to get list of rows where the date is today:

```
AND DATEPART("month", a.PersonBirthdate) = DATEPART("month", GetDate())
AND DATEPART("day", a.PersonBirthdate) = DATEPART("day", GetDate())
```

Comment: Check if DATEADD works in sql server 2005: `DATEADD (MONTH, 1, GetDate())`

Comment: @Antonio - although [the docs say it started in 2008](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), I can confirm it does work in 2005.  Also 1 month != 30 days

Comment: @Rain - just a small point, but there are 31 days in July, so adding 30 to the 1st of July would result in the 31st of July... not the 1st of August

Comment: @Rain, that's why the example I provided it's with MONTH and not DAY. I tested it in Sql Server 2008 and if you use it like `select DATEADD (MONTH, 1, GetDate())` it gives result `2019-08-04 09:21:02.220`, which is exactly 1 month after today. In the same way, if you use `-1` instead of `1`, it gives you 1 month back.

Comment: @Antonio - who are you directing that comment to?  The OP hasn't responded, and I am the one who is pointing out the 30 days != 1 month... but the OP has specifically said "where the date is exactly in 30 days from today". So your use of 1 month would be incorrect

Comment: Time to update to a supported version of SQL Server.

Comment: @freefaller my mistake:-P If it's exactly 30 days from the date it would be `DATEADD (DAY, 30, GetDate())`

Comment: Your first code snippet checks for the _current_ month (`DATEPART("month", GetDate())`) and a day number that is 30 days hence (`DATEPART("day", GetDate()+30)`). In most cases 30 days later will be in the _next_ month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To calculate today plus 30 days as a `Date` you can use:

```
DateAdd( day, 30, Cast( GetDate() as Date ) )
```

Note that if you are trying to retrieve rows by a `DateTime` column that have that date you would use:

```
where DateAdd( day, 30, Cast( GetDate() as Date ) ) <= DateTimeColumn and
  DateTimeColumn < DateAdd( day, 31, Cast( GetDate() as Date ) )
```

This will include all times up to, but not including, midnight starting the following day. The condition is [SARGABLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) so that it can benefit from indexes.

Answer (score 1):

I created a UDF years ago called `GetJustDate` which returns a just the date, and removes all hours/minutes/seconds/etc..

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetJustDate] (@DATE datetime)
RETURNS datetime AS  
BEGIN 
    RETURN DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @DATE))
END
```

If you use that and add 30 days to it, you'll get just the date in the future that you want to match...

```
DECLARE @FUTURE DATETIME = DATEADD(d, 30, dbo.GetJustDate(@DATE))
```

Once you have that you can compare the date in the row (after getting just the date) to the new variable...

```
AND dbo.GetJustDate(a.PersonBirthdate) = @FUTURE
```

---

Alternatively if you don't want to use the UDF, then simply use the DATEADD/DATEDIFF directly...

```
DECLARE @FUTURE DATETIME = DATEADD(dd, 30, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @DATE))
AND DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, a.PersonBirthdate)) = @FUTURE
```

Answer (score 0):

Very, very easy way that you can get the right one is this:

```
SELECT DATEPART(DD, CAST(GETDATE()+30 as date ))
```

Although Datepart is not the fastest one, so I suppose that first you need to define for yourself why you need first to check the month, and then the date.